# Does setting an object to null while iterating over a HashMap have any effect on the object's state

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this simple program, where I am iterating over the map and setting the object to null instead of updating the value to null inside map. I am wondering why it is not allowing me to nullify the object but if I change any value of the object while iterating, Objects appears as changed, Please help me understand this behaviour. (This question might sound like a newbie)

```
Map<String, MyObj> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", new MyObj("XYZ"));
map.put("b", new MyObj("FOO"));
map.put("c", new MyObj("BAR"));

System.out.println(map);

// output : {a=sample.MyObj@15db9742, b=sample.MyObj@6d06d69c, c=sample.MyObj@7852e922}
for(Entry<String, MyObj> e : map.entrySet()){
        MyObj o = e.getValue();
        //set the object to null
        o = null;

}
// printing map to see if values are null now.
System.out.println(map);

// output : {a=sample.MyObj@15db9742, b=sample.MyObj@6d06d69c, c=sample.MyObj@7852e922}
```

Comment: You are making a copy of the object reference, so setting that copy to null does not change the original object reference.

Comment: There is no such thing as "setting an object to null" You can set a reference to null but only that reference changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things coming into play here: local scope of variables, and the behavior of reference types compared to primitive types.

When you have `for (MyObj i : map.values().toArray(ar))`, `i` is local to the scope of the `for` and merely points to instances of `MyObj`. It is a *copy* of the reference. When you set `i` to null, you've simply changed the local value of `i` (i.e., the copy); the original reference still points to the original instance. Since `i` only *points* to instances of `MyObj`, you aren't changing instances of `MyObj` itself. Really, when you set something to `null`, you're only saying that it doesn't point to something. When it is non-null, it points to an instance of its type.

However, if you do something *with* `i`, by calling a method perhaps, you are calling it on the *instance* that `i` *points to*. This is because both the original reference and the copy *point to the same thing*. So you end up *modifying the object itself*. For example, let's say you do `i.setFoo(10)`, then you will be modifying the instance of `MyObj` that `i` points to, and setting the value of `foo` on that instance to `10`.

It is important to understand that with **reference types**, simply reassigning the value of the variable to `null` (or any other instance) *does not modify the object that it points to*. All you've done is made the variable point to *something else* (or nothing at all in the case of `null`).

Now you will also see the same thing if you had an array of primitives (let's say `int[]`):

```
for(int i : intArr) {
    i = 10;
}
```

This will not set every location in `intArr` to 10. Why? This is because `i` is again a **local variable** in this case. So this `i` is a copy of a value in `intArr`. So when you reassign the value to something else, you simply changed the value of the *copy* and not the original.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't. It won't change a thing in map, as you are assigning null to local variable.
That local variable used to refer to map value earlier, but refer to null now, without changing the map value itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `o` as a variable that holds a memory address where the `MyObj` instance is located. When you write `o = null` you remove the memory address from `o` but that does not affect the `MyObj` object.

In practice it's a bit more complicated but, essentially, that's how it works.